# В чём разница между запросами?

Tags: python, golang, api

Для запроса к API сайта нужен пост с определёнными параметрами.
В документации был указан пример на языке Go:

```
resp, err := http.PostForm("site-url", url.Values{"query": {"release"}, "code":{"something"})
```

Но мне нужно было перевести его в python, получилось так:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("site-url", data={"query":"release", "code": "something"})
```

Но это не работает. Подскажите, в чём разница между двумя примерами?
В первом случае API Принимает запрос и отвечает, а во втором возвращает ошибку - No query

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Приведите больше информации.

Comment: Ставишь [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) и смотришь разницу.

Comment: @CrazyElf Во втором случае ошибка - нет запроса (No query)

Answer (score 0):

Как верно заметили в комментариях, чтобы увидеть, в чём разница запросов отправляемых на сервер, вам надо поставить сниффер (например, Fiddler) и посмотреть что-же на самом деле происходит.

На Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    os.Setenv("HTTP_PROXY", "127.0.0.1:8888") // адрес и порт, который слушает Fiddler

    resp, err := http.PostForm("http://httpbin.org/post", url.Values{"query": {"release"}, "code": {"something"}})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Fiddler показывает, что ушёл вот такой запрос:

```
POST http://httpbin.org/post HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip

code=something&query=release
```

На Python:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
  "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
}

r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data={"query":"release", "code": "something"}, proxies=proxies)

print(r.content)
```

Уходит:

```
POST http://httpbin.org/post HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.19.1
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

query=release&code=something
```

Как можно заметить, различия не существенны и можно сказать что и Go, и Python **отправляют одно и тоже**. Да, в Python отличается UserAgent, параметры формы идут в другом порядке, есть пара дополнительных заголовков, но всё в пределах допустимого и это никак не должно влиять на разбор запроса сервером.

P.S. В обоих случаях, дополнительно ещё и тестовый сервер (httpbin.org) отвечает, какие заголовки и post он получил. И там тоже всё Ok:

```
 "args": {},                                                             
 "data": "",                                                             
 "files": {},                                                            
 "form": {                                                               
   "code": "something",                                                  
   "query": "release"                                                    
 },                                                                      
 "headers": {                                                            
   "Accept": "*/*",                                                      
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",                                   
   "Content-Length": "28",                                               
   "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",                  
   "Host": "httpbin.org",                                                
   "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.19.1",                               
   "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5e7a57a4-b9d57d24be4ebb4aa940d53e"         
 },                                                                      
 "json": null,                                                           
 "origin": "xxx",                                             
 "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
```